# Выбрать минимальное значение MIN

Tags: sql, база-данных, ms-access

В запросе нужно получить фамилию врача, у которого было минимальное количество пациентов на приеме в указанную дату.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исользовать `MIN` и `COUNT`  в запросе одновременно? То есть, вначале нужно посчитать количество пациентов у всех врачей в указанную дату, а потом вывести врача с минимальным кол-вом пациентов.

```
SELECT ([Врачи]![Фамилия]), 
       (COUNT([Пациенты.Код])) AS [кол-во]
  FROM Пациенты 
  INNER JOIN (Врачи INNER JOIN Прием 
                      ON Врачи.Код = Прием.КтоВрач) 
    ON Пациенты.Код = Прием.КтоПациент
  WHERE ((([введите дату])=[Прием]![ДатаПриема]))
GROUP BY ([Врачи]![Фамилия]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.Фамилия, 
       MIN(T.Kол-во) 
FROM (SELECT Врачи.Фамилия AS Фамилия, 
             COUNT(p.Код) AS Kол-во 
       FROM Пациенты AS P
       INNER JOIN Врачи AS V 
         ON  P.Код = V.КтоПациент
       INNER JOIN Прием AS PM 
         ON V.Код = PM.КтоВрач
       WHERE PM.ДатаПриема = @введите_дату 
     GROUP BY V.Фамилия) T;
```